# How to Setup Project Developed by C# 3.5 on Windows 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

i have Developed a Project using C# 3.5 and MSSQL 2005 ,, and after publishing it ,, it does  not setup in any windows 64-bit on the Clients PCs ,,
The Problem is the Project is 32-bit and your PC is 46-bit ,
PS. the project i developed in was 32-bit .
What should i do to Solve this Problem ??

Comment: You should probably tell us how you created the setup project. If I had to guess how you did it, I'd have to say you did it wrong. If you want a more helpful answer, then please help us by showing us what you did.

Comment: i have Published it ,, right click on the Project name > Publish > and set the properties and Publish

Comment: @Omneya: That doesn't create a setup project. Do you have a setup project in your solution? Maybe you should give enough detail for someone else to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @John : may i ask what is the Diff. between Setup a project and Publish it ?

Comment: @Omneya: a "Setup Project" is a kind of project, it is not a command. Please provide some information about your solution in Visual Studio. Is there one project or more than one? What kind of project? What is the project configuration? What parameters are you supplying to the Publish command, etc.

Comment: developing Desktop Application with C# ,, it is only one project ,, i have finished the development , so i wanna give the user an EXE to use the Application , my Windows is 32-bit and the user's 64-bit and i have published it wizard

Answer (score 0):

Normally *safe* managed projects build IL assemblies that are neutral from the target architecture point of view. An assembly created on a 32bit development environment works fine on a 64 bit machine, as long as the proper 64bit .Net Framework is installed on that machine. Problems appear only if you use unsafe constructs, like PInvoke, or if you specifically build your assemblies for a target platform.

Now the question is why did you tag this question SQL Server 2005 and .Net 3.5? SQLCLR assemblies for SQL 2005 support only .Net 2.0. When deploying a SQLCLR assembly on a 64bit SQL Server, the .Net 2.0 64 bit must be, obviously, installed.